# Package for coturn

Tags: networking, apt

Is there a package for [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)? If yes, what repository should I add?

I googled and I got this http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/coturn or http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coturn.

I enabled universe repository (`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"` or `sudo add-apt-repository universe`) and then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Running `sudo apt-get install coturn`, I still get *E: Unable to locate package coturn*.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but vivid packages are for 15.04. Is there some way that I can still use them?

Comment: did you tried `apt-cache search coturn`? any findings?

Comment: Tried - got nothing :(.

Comment: make sure you update your repository with `apt-get update`. if no result then you have your answer.

Comment: I did that too. Still nothing. I googled and I got that http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coturn. How can I use it?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Xenial is another ubuntu codename development for 16.04 LTS, you cant uses its packages for another release.

Comment: I guess that's the same for vivid, right? I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Vivid is 15.04, which is different.

Comment: I meant that I cannot use that either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30854/discussion-between-adrian-ber-and-aizuddin-zali).

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, yes: there is a package for Coturn. You don't need to add any repositories because it is already in the official one. The 2 links you found are from the official repository, and can be downloaded manually.

Since you are on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and the packages are only available for 15.04 and newer, they are not included in your repository because they are incompatible. Nothing is stopping you from manually downloading them, but you would likely have compatibility issues with many other packages.

To be more precise, Vivid is for 15.04, Wily is for 15.10, and Xenial is for 16.04 LTS.

This package is not included in 22.04 due to a bug, but a patched version is available for 22.10 "kinetic". There is also an unofficial backport repository at [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/coturn](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/coturn)

Comment: It is not present in 22.04. 
It was present in 18.04 and 20.04 thou.

Comment: @Orphans, I updated my answer with additional information about this.

Answer (score -2):

Simple Install from Debian repository for Ubuntu 14.0.4 
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/coturn/download

Download and Install with `dpkg -i package_name.deb`

Any issues `apt-get -f install`

Done now you have ready the package

For activate us daemon
`nano /etc/default/coturn` and uncomment the Line

Comment: I not have idea where Mostafa say is a bad system possible if hi Like to edit other people comments hi can also post How to in Ubuntu 14.0.4 your -2 not have sense You can explain better system